# Por que esse código redigitado não funciona igual o original?

Tags: c#, array, c++

Estou estudando C++ à pouco tempo e quero treinar reescrevendo funções já feitas por mim em C# só que em C++.

Eu escrevi um código simples que calcula um `IV` de um Hash, bem simples mesmo, chamando os mesmos métodos usando o mesmo argumento em ambos métodos os retornos são diferentes e não entendi porquê.

*`CalcIV(byte[] data)`* em **C#**:

```
    public static byte CalcIV(byte[] pass) {
        int iv = 0;
        foreach(byte k in pass) {
            iv += k;
            iv *= k + 1;
        }
        return (byte)(iv / pass.Length);
    }
```

*`calc_iv(byte buffer[])`* em **C++**:

```
#include <iostream>

typedef unsigned char byte;

byte calc_iv(byte buffer[])
{
    int iv = 0;
    size_t len = sizeof(buffer); // get buffer size
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        byte I = buffer[i];
        iv += I;
        iv *= I + 1;
    }
    return iv / (len);
}
```

E o que é retornado é o seguinte:

```
// Em C#
byte[] data = new byte[] {41, 32, 16};
return CalcIV(data);
// Resultado é 152

// Em C++
byte buf[] = {41, 32, 16};
byte iv = calc_iv(buf);
return iv;
// Resultado é 50
```

Ambos resultados deviam ser iguais, mas não entendo porquê em C# o mesmo código dá **152** e em C++ dá **50**.

Alguém me explica?

Comment: coloca pra funcionar no ideone: https://ideone.com/ e eu começaria testando pelos operadores `+=` e `*=` não sei como se comportam no C++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> e em C++ dá 50.

Nem por isso, porque o programa tem um comportamento indeterminado logo pode dar um valor qualquer como resultado, algo que pode confirmar [aqui](https://ideone.com/hKfDCE)

O problema dá-se aqui:

```
size_t len = sizeof(buffer); // get buffer size
```

Uma vez que um array em C é um ponteiro para o primeiro elemento, este `sizeof` obtêm apenas o tamanho do ponteiro `buffer`, que será normalmente `4` bytes. Nessa situação o `for` executa `4` vezes e acede a um elemento fora do array, apanhando assim um valor aleatório na memória.

Pode resolver este problema de algumas formas:

1. Passando o tamanho também como parâmetro:

   Esta é uma solução comum em C puro, em que as funções que utilizam arrays recebem sempre o tamanho deles. Uma exceção seria uma string pois o final pode ser determinado pelo `'\0'`.

   ```
   byte calc_iv(byte buffer[], size_t len)
   {
       int iv = 0;
       for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          byte I = buffer[i];
          iv += I;
          iv *= I + 1;
      }
      return iv / (len);
   }
   ```

   E chamando no `main` assim:

   ```
   byte iv = calc_iv(buf, sizeof(buf)/sizeof(buf[0]));
   ```

   No main o compilador consegue determinar o tamanho total do vetor alocado pois é feita uma alocação estática, logo `sizeof(buf)` irá dar o tamanho total do array em bytes, que ao dividir pelo tamanho do primeiro elemento em bytes, resulta na quantidade de elementos do array.

   O mesmo já não pode ser feito dentro da função pois não existe forma de saber como o array foi construído, e o array não tem qualquer informação de tamanho associada. É meramente um ponteiro para o primeiro elemento.

   [Veja este código a correr no Ideone](https://ideone.com/qweEaJ)
2. Passando apenas um `vector`

   Este cenário é o mais parecido ao C# pois o `vector` tem informação do tamanho internamente, não sendo assim necessário enviar mais nenhuma informação:

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <vector>

   typedef unsigned char byte;

   byte calc_iv(std::vector<byte> buffer)
   {
       int iv = 0;
       for(int i = 0; i < buffer.size(); i++) {
           byte I = buffer[i];
           iv += I;
           iv *= I + 1;
       }
       return iv / buffer.size();
   }


   int main(){
       std::vector<byte> buf = {41, 32, 16};
       byte iv = calc_iv(buf);
       std::cout<<(int)iv<<std::endl;

      return 0;
   }
   ```

   [Veja este exemplo também no Ideone](https://ideone.com/oHvZOA)

   Neste caso foi necessário adicionar o `#include <vector>` no topo, e o `len` foi trocado diretamente pelo `buffer.size()`.

   Para poder instanciar o `vector` no `main` da forma que eu fiz tem de compilar com C++11 ou superior.

Comment: Posso substituir a linha do tamanho por um `size_t len = sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(buf[0]);` ao invés de passar como um parâmetro?

Comment: @CypherPotato Se está a falar dentro da função não irá funcionar, porque dentro da função `sizeof(buffer)` é mesmo só o tamanho do ponteiro. No `main` funciona, porque foi onde foi criado o array.