# Erro com array em C - arduino

Tags: c, array, arduino

Estou tendo erro para assinar um array:

```
Menu m = Menu();
m.Options[4] = {"teste1","teste2","teste3","teste4"};//Erro aqui
m.Show();
```

Classe Menu:

```
class Menu
{
public:
    String Options[];
    int index = 0;
    int len = 0;
    String Show()
    {
        while(controller.Button == 0)
        {
        len = sizeof(Options)/sizeof(Options[0]);
            index = index + controller.Left;
            if (index < 0)
            index = len;
            if (index > len)
            index = 0;
            display.setCursor(0,00);
            Clear();
            display.println(Options[index]);
            DrawBuffer();
        }
        return Options[index];
    }
 };
```

Eu já tentei:
`m.Options[] = {"teste1","teste2","teste3","teste4"};` e `m.Options = {"teste1","teste2","teste3","teste4"};`, 
Também não funcionou.

Este é o erro: `no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'String' and '<brace-enclosed initializer list>')`

Sou iniciante em C.

Comment: Como foi definida a classe `Menu` ?

Comment: @Isac Acabei de incluir a classe Menu na pergunta

Comment: Quando um array é definido de forma estática tem de ter os elementos atribuídos nesse momento e/ou o tamanho. Para ser atribuído mais tarde tem de ser definido de forma estática e instanciado com `malloc` ou `new` que será mais apropriado para o seu exemplo uma vez que é C++ e não C. E mesmo o tamanho terá de ser guardado pois não será possível de o saber mais tarde. [Respondi a uma pergunta ainda ontem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264664/por-que-esse-c%C3%B3digo-redigitado-n%C3%A3o-funciona-igual-o-original/264671#264671) com um problema parecido

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode definir um tamanho fixo para um array dinâmico de forma explicita. É uma regra dos arrays tanto para o C quanto para C++

Ex de erros:

```
int array[]; //eu sou dinâmico

main(){
   array[4] = {1,2,3,4}; //definindo tamanho para um array dinâmico? isso tá errado :/

cin << array; //recebendo valores de forma dinamica
```

talvez seja possível isso `array[]= {valores};`

Faz tempo que não trabalho com arrays, mas lembro desse regra.